# Как изменить значение переменной, переданной в шаблон, в самом шаблоне?

Tags: python-3.x, html5, django

есть вот такой шаблон:

```
{% for basket_element in basket_elements %}
  <tr>
    <td class="image">
      <img src="/{{ basket_element.image.url }}/" alt="картинка не работает" width="170" height="200">
    </td>
    <td class="text">{{ basket_element.latin_name }}</td>
    <td class="text">{{ basket_element.price }} руб</td>
    <td class="text">
      <form class="" action="{% url 'quantity' basket_element.id %}">
        <input name="quantity" class="quantity" type="text" value="1">
        <button type="submit">
          <img src="{% static 'img/reload.png' %}" alt="reload">
        </button>
      </form>
    </td>
    <td class="text">
      {% if coming %}
        {{ price }}
        {% with coming=False %}
        {% endwith %}
      {% else %}
        {{ basket_element.price }}
      {% endif %}
      </td>
    <td class="text">удалить</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

мне надо, чтобы после того, как if сработал программа более в него не попадала. Для этого мне нужно поменять значение переменной coming на false в самом шаблоне. Как мне это сделать?

Comment: Советую бросить эту затею. Чем-то похоже на проблему XY. Вы не должны перемещать логику из представления в шаблон. Если Вам требуется это, то, скорее всего, Вы что-то упустили в представлении. Именно оно занимается всей логикой.

Comment: хорошо. я перезадам свой вопрос